# How can I add a second Open Graph image to a site using Yoast?

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, open-graph

Through the Yoast SEO plugin, I've added a 1200 by 630 image for use by sites like Facebook and LinkedIn (and the image shows up with a complete set of og meta tags).

I want to add a second open graph image (a square one) for use by WhatsApp (WhatsApp selects the last image and crops it to a 1 by 1.3 portrait aspect ratio and then displays it at 80 by 104 pixels, which doesn't work well with the image layout that works well with Facebook (and LinkedIn).

I don't think Yoast directly supports a second image, but is there a way using functions.php to add a second image (with the op:image, og:image:secure_url, og:image:height, og:image:width, and og:image:alt meta fields)? I wouldn't need the image data to be done programmatically, as I would use the same image for every page, so the information could be hard coded into functions.php.

Thanks for the help.

*I've reposted the question at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57519145/how-can-i-add-a-second-open-graph-image-to-a-site-using-yoast) for help with the PHP code.*

Comment: How comfortable with coding are you?

Comment: @MatthewBrown - I'm okay with coding if I can get pointed in the right direction. I found a tutorial by Igor Benić from a couple of years ago that an add_action function to hook into wpseo_opengraph, but couldn't get it to work (the code replaced the og:image, not add a second image).